# Re-Call a String/Object from previous Sub

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to recall a string or object that was stored in a previous sub?
The below code gives you an idea as to what I am trying to do.

```
Sub StoreUserData()
Dim StorName as Object
End 

Sub WriteUserFile()
'Recall StorName here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make it into a field:

```
Dim StorName as Object

Sub StoreUserData()
  'Do stuff with  StoreName
End 

Sub WriteUserFile()
'Recall StorName here
End Sub
```

If it is declared within a method, it is a local variable and not visible outside the method.

I suggest reading about [Scope in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are only accessible within their respective code block. To be able to access it you would have to widen its scope like this:

```
Class MyClass

    Dim storName as Object

    Sub StoreUserData()
        storName = something
    End Sub

    Sub WriteUserFile()
        ' Use storName here
    End Sub

End Class
```